# Rails find records using an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

(Select Query by Pair of fields using an `in` clause)

I have an array of hashes that looks like this:

`[ {product_id: 7629, group_id: 4}, {product_id: 8202, group_id: 3} ]`

What I would like to return are all the records in the `Items` table that match the pair of fields in the array.

In SQL it would be retrieved like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items
WHERE (product_id, group_id) IN (VALUES (7629,4), (8202,3))
```

But I am having trouble doing this with a rails `.where` clause. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no benefit in using SQL's `IN` in this case.

I would use `where` for the first condition and chain all other conditions with [`or`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) (and let Rails take care of sanitizing and heavy lifting):

```
array = [{ product_id: 7629, group_id: 4 }, { product_id: 8202, group_id: 3 }]
array[1..-1].inject(Model.where(array[0])) { |m, h| m.or(Model.where(h)) }
```

Comment: Nice! This is much better than the one I proposed. However, it is modifying the `array` with `array.shift`, which I don't think is ideal. `array.drop(1).inject(Model.where(array.first)) { |m, h| m.or(Model.where(h)) }` would do the same thing without mutating the array.

Comment: Updated my answer to address that.

Comment: @spickermann i like the simplicity of this vs. building the "where IN" myself. Do you know if there's any performance difference between many OR clause vs. the "where IN [some_array]" ?

Comment: @user137717 It probably depends on what database you use (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Maria, etc...). But in general I expect all newer DBs to be clever enough to understand that `foo = 1 OR foo = 2` is basically the same as `foo IN (1, 2)`. You also might want to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67510316/2483313).

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of any way to do this without resorting to SQL, even with Arel.

Since arrays can't be quoted, we have to do some silly stuff to still allow it to be sanitized. This isn't a *great* solution, but it is a working one.

```
your_hashes = [ {product_id: 7629, group_id: 4}, {product_id: 8202, group_id: 3} ]

# turn hashes into simple value array
conditions = your_hashes.map { |h| [ h[:product_id], h[:group_id] ] }
=> [[7629, 4], [8202, 3]]

# create a list of "(?)" values that will allow the conditions to be passed in
values = ("(?)," * conditions.length)[0..-2]
=> "(?),(?)"

# use it to look up the values
Model.where("(product_id, group_id) IN (VALUES #{values})", *conditions)

# this is the generated sql:
SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE ((product_id, group_id) IN (VALUES (7629,4),(8202,3)))
```

Comment: Consider using `values = (['(?)'] * conditions.length).join(',')` to avoid the really quirky `[0..-2]` comma-stripping thing at the end. It's better to not put in garbage that you're going to immediately remove.

Comment: @tadman That is usually a good point, but this was intentional. That alternative array syntax is 3.71x slower than the string slicing I used. It's not as pretty but it's quite a bit more performant.