# How to apply lists of filter values on two columns in lock-step?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let's assume I have the table with below columns and records:

```
id shop_id product_id
1  1       1
2  1       2
3  2       1
4  2       3
```

I want to run single query to get ID 1 and ID 4 records when query looks like this:

```rb
ShopProduct.where(shop_id: 1, product_id: 1).where(shop_id: 2, product_id: 3)
```

The problem is when I try to simplify like this:

```rb
ShopProduct.where(shop_id: [1,2], product_id: [1,3])
```

Then I get *three* records, not two as expected.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for few input pairs: [ROW values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   "ShopProduct"
WHERE  (shop_id, product_id) IN ((1,1), (2,3));
```

Related:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)

If you have two long arrays you want to process in "lock-step", other forms may be faster / more convenient. Like: unnest two arrays in parallel (in lock-step), then join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   unnest('{1,2}'::int[], '{1,3}'::int[]) t(shop_id, product_id)
JOIN   "ShopProduct" USING (shop_id, product_id);
```

There is an overloaded version of the function [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) that accepts multiple input arrays. See:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b415fdc068b0984b0d7deeaa4eb0b276)*

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with [or condition](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions) starting from rails 5

```
ShopProduct.where(shop_id: 1, product_id: 1).or(ShopProduct.where(shop_id: 2, product_id: 3))
```

Related:

[Rails find records using an array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361875/rails-find-records-using-an-array-of-hashes)