# Query performance questions (WHERE field IN array)

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift, query-optimization

I'm creating a simple form-based tool to generate repeated queries using string concatenation formulas, and was wondering how much effect the following inefficiencies have on query performance:

#### A) Equals vs. IN a 1-element array:

1. `WHERE FieldName = 'foo'`

   - vs.
2. `WHERE FieldName IN ('foo')`
   *(form field accepts 1 or more values; it's easier to always put it in an array than differentiate between the cases)*

#### B) Having redundant/repeated values in an array:

1. `WHERE FieldName IN ('lorem','ipsum','dolor','sit','amet')`

   - vs.
2. `WHERE FieldName IN ('sit','ipsum','sit','dolor','ipsum','lorem','amet','ipsum','dolor','ipsum')`
   *(actual arrays might have 20 unique values out of 200)*

In both examples, it requires a bit more up-front work to generate (1) than (2). 
I *could* add conditions to generate <strike>(2)</strike> (1); I'm just trying to figure out whether it's worth the effort.

The data sources have millions of records, and (obviously) this is just a small part of much more complex queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: **I could add conditions to generate (2);** - why would you want (2)?

Comment: A 1 & 2 will likely be identical, I suspect B also, the only difference is likely to parse/compile time which is negligible. You can easily investigate which is better by running the query in whatever your RDBMS is and looking at the execution plan operators.

Comment: Edited post in response to 1st 2 comments:
Tagged DBMS: Tables exist in both SQL Server & Redshift (slightly different date ranges); Corrected typo that it would be more work in each case to generate (1) than (2).

Answer (score 0):

The query planners (sometimes called query compilers) in recent versions of various makes and model of SQL table server understand both `col = 'val'` and `col IN ('val')` and treat them the same, generating the same query plan for both. One formulation of the query may take dozens of nanoseconds longer than the other. That doesn't matter. At all.

Query planners also understand that a list of constants given in `IN (whatever)` is formally a set, and will remove duplicates. For constants, that's part of the query planner's job.

If you use `WHERE col IN (SELECT something FROM table WHERE whatever)` and the set inside your `IN` clause gets very large, you may need to analyze the performance of your query with `EXPLAIN` or whatever your table server supports. You may need to add appropriate indexes.

If you're using some ancient version, your mileage will vary.

So, as usual, trust your query planner. Write your code so it's easy to read, modify, and reason about.